# How to use AVG() function after GROUP BY with CASE in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Im learning SQL and i did this code (ignore words in portuguese):

```
SELECT EMBALAGEM,
CASE 
    WHEN PRECO_DE_LISTA >= 12 THEN 'PRODUTO_CARO'
    WHEN PRECO_DE_LISTA >= 7 AND PRECO_DE_LISTA < 12 THEN 'PRODUTO_EM_CONTA'
    ELSE 'PRODUTO_BARATO' 
END AS STATUS_PRECO, AVG(PRECO_DE_LISTA) AS PRECO_MEDIO
FROM tabela_de_produtos
GROUP BY EMBALAGEM,
CASE 
    WHEN PRECO_DE_LISTA >= 12 THEN 'PRODUTO_CARO'
    WHEN PRECO_DE_LISTA >= 7 AND PRECO_DE_LISTA < 12 THEN 'PRODUTO_EM_CONTA'
    ELSE 'PRODUTO_BARATO' 
END;
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TedKP.png

After that, I've tried to take the average from the column created with CASE ("PRECO_MEDIO") using:

```
SELECT AVG(PRECO_MEDIO) AS AVERAGE FROM (the previous code);
```

But didn't work, I've got this error: Every derived table must have its own alias.
How can i do the mean of that column?

Comment: Simply add an alias to your derived table (i.e., subquery in `FROM` clause): `...FROM (the previous code) AS myalias`

Comment: @Parfait you should make that an answer

Comment: Oh, didnt know about that must have alias, thanks :)